# How to run a Windows app in an isolated environment and capture footage from it?

Tags: windows, java, computing-environment

I have a game that has demo exporting. I want to be able to render said demos without taking my full desktop. I also don't want my game data to interfere with the rendering of the demo.

Is there a Windows command or some sort of Java library that will let me do this?

VSync is required for all layers as I want no broken or half-rendered frames.

Comment: This requires a third-party application that creates a sandbox environment.  Plenty of options.  Additionally, if your talking about UWP applications, they are already sandboxed.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox is a very powerful solution that will meet your needs.

Using the following command you can capture screenshots/video. (You will have to adjust the command based on the name of your VM, and the filename you want to save the output): https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-controlvm:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm vm_name screenshotpng
```

To capture video use https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvm-videocap:

```
VBoxManage controlvm vm_name videocapscreens
```

You can also do this using the VirtualBox GUI tool: http://geekthis.net/post/virtualbox-video-capture/

Comment: Will I be able to VSync everything? I don't want partially rendered frames.

Comment: That's a additional detail you should probably add to your question above. It will most likely work, as VirtualBox is used for all kinds of virtualization in development, but I haven't checked whether vsync works or not. You can download one of the VMs from here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ and quickly check if it works or not..